# Magento2 Capture event

Tags: magento2, payment-methods

I am creating payment method but I don't want use capture event but in capture event we get payment variable like in below code

```
public function capture(InfoInterface $payment, $amount)
{
    // Normal checkout payments in Authorize & Capture mode
    $this->achapi->createCharge($payment, $amount, false);
    return $this;
}
```

Here you can see payment variable. I want this variable in public function `assignData(\Magento\Framework\DataObject $data)` can I get this here